# Swapping keys and values of a map in C++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a function in C++ that  for swap the contents of a map ... 
that is:
those that were the keys now become the items and those that the items were now the keys. 
Can you tell me if there is something about this?

Comment: You might want to do this for multimaps, since values in a map are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: I am sure that the values ​​of my map are all unique: There are no
duplicate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Geoffroy said, `std::map` doesn't allow this behaviour. However, you might want to use a STL-like container [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) - bidirectorial map.

> A Bimap is a data structure that represents bidirectional relations between elements of two collections. The container is designed to work as two opposed STL maps. A bimap between a collection X and a collection Y can be viewed as a map from X to Y (this view will be called the left map view) or as a map from Y to X (known as the right map view).

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard method / way to do this, you have to write your own function.

It's not something very hard to do, but first think about doing it in a different way.

If you have to invert your key/values, then you're code may be ill-though, you don't keep the logic of the container.

If you want more information, explain why you want to do this.

Comment: I think boost has an iterator adaptor that might make this easy

Comment: Yes perhaps, I don't know that much about boost for the moment. But it's not too hard to do.

Comment: I have to read a file that took the row-id string. I need for my algorithms that this value is an integer (for reasons of efficiency and not a string) use a map to associate with these strings a id unique. In the map so I intID-string. I need to have the results of my algorithm in my old format id-string so I have, for each IdInt search string in all the corresponding values ​​of the map. To speed this can do a swap

Answer (score 1):

Insert the items in the map into a multimap - value first, key second, with appropriate comparison function that compares two values of the original map. Once all value-key items are inserted, the multimap will be sorted as intended. Job done!